# Event to Fetch all actions under a controller in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

After a lot of search, I was unable to find any method/service (may be there is) from which i am able to Fetch all Actions under some controller.
P.S i am unable to provide any snippet as there merely no help/documentation regarding this.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by fetching all actions? Do you want a list of class methods for a given controller (php's native get_class_methods function)? Do you want an event that you can listen to when a controller action is called? It's not particularly clear what you're trying to do or the result you're expecting from your question.

Comment: Use Reflection. PHP has this, but Zend has a wrapper for PHP's  reflection functionality http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php

Comment: i am talking about some thing like this =>Do you want an event that you can listen to when a controller action is called